# Подсчет нажатий inline кнопок в telegram-bot

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot

Мой телеграм бот будет принимать входящие сообщения (алерты) через вебхук от Datadog. Хочу понять, как лучше отслеживать ложные срабатывания алертов. Сейчас я просто добавил две кнопки под каждое сообщение, чтобы после проверки сервиса на который прилетел алерт, нажать на соответствующую (валиден или нет). Чтобы потом можно было скажем подсчитать сколько ложных было за неделю. Но как лучше это реализовать не понимаю пока. Спасибо.

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(text="btn1")
async def process_callback_button1(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery):
    await bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query.id)
    await bot.send_message(callback_query.from_user.id, 'Этот алерт валиден')


@dp.callback_query_handler(text="btn2")
async def process_callback_button1(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery):
    await bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query.id)
    await bot.send_message(callback_query.from_user.id, 'Ложное срабатывание')
```